# Why is this happening with my variables?

Tags: php

```
<?php

// $searchResult is type of Outcome
// This is what we do:
dList::lessAnchor($searchResult)->showElement();
dList::moreAnchor($searchResult)->showElement();

/**
* @returns vAnchor (can get showed with showElement() - not part of the problem)
*/
public static function lessAnchor(Outcome $searchResult){
  $searchData = $searchResult->searchData;
  $searchData->Page = $searchData->Page - 1; // (!1)
  return self::basicAnchor($searchData, "Back");
}

/**
* @returns vAnchor (can get showed with showElement() - not part of the problem)
*/
public static function moreAnchor(Outcome $searchResult){
  $searchData=$searchResult->searchData;
  $searchData->Page = $searchData->Page + 1; // (!2)
  return self::basicAnchor($searchData, "More");
}
```

When I call `dList::lessAnchor()` on `$searchResult`, it modifies the property of `$searchData->Page` by decreasing it by 1 as you see, marked at line with `(!1)`.
After a while (one line below), I call `dList::moreAnchor()` on `$searchResult` again.

Why do I see `Page` attribute decreased by 1 at `(!2)` mark? I did not pass `$searchResult` by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php): this is intended behaviour.

> As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. **When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable**, the different variables are not aliases: **they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object**.

if you want to avoid this, you should [clone your object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) where neccessary. it's just like this:

```
public static function lessAnchor(Outcome $searchResult){
  $searchData = clone $newResult->searchData; //$searchData now is a new object
  $searchData->Page=$searchData->Page-1; // (!1)
  return self::basicAnchor($searchData,"Back");
}
```

Comment: Wow, now I didn't expect this. Should I clone the object on function call? - Okay, I've got it. Thank you for your advice and quality